# Set WIX MSI Package to write log to same file as the bootstrapper/burn log file

Tags: wix

I have a log file that is written to the installation directory by the MSI. This log file contains code I've written to help with troubleshooting installation issues within the MSI package. The bootstrapper also has its own automatic log file. Is there a way for me to set my MSI to log to the same file as the bootstrapper?

**Why do I want to do this?**

If an install fails, the bootstrapper displays an error screen with a link to the bootstrapper's log file. This is the information my clients send me when they have problems during installation, but this information is useless to me. I'd love it if this log could also capture all of my MSI troubleshooting information.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path of yout bootstrapper file and store it in a variable , then when u executing the msi file

```
"/c msiexec /i Blabla.msi /L*v bootstrapperLogFilePath"
```